# Why do ntpdate queries take twice as long to execute in 12.04 than 10.04?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04

When I run  'time ntpdate -qd ntp.ubuntu.com' it takes twice as long to run in Ubuntu 12.04 than it does in Ubuntu 10.04.  I've tested this on several physical and virtual machines with similar results.  (Don't fret about the fact that the server is unable to reach the ntp destination)

Ubuntu 12.04:

```
# time ntpdate -qd ntp.ubuntu.com
14 Jul 23:33:30 ntpdate[12313]: ntpdate 4.2.6p3@1.2290-o Tue Jun  5 20:12:09 UT)
Looking for host ntp.ubuntu.com and service ntp
host found : europium.canonical.com
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
91.189.94.4: Server dropped: no data
server 91.189.94.4, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [91.189.94.4], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 16:00:00.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 16:00:00.000
transmit timestamp:  d3ace2c1.9d594e0f  Sat, Jul 14 2012 23:33:37.614
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

14 Jul 23:33:39 ntpdate[12313]: no server suitable for synchronization found

real    0m8.665s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Ubuntu 10.04:

```
# time ntpdate -qd ntp.ubuntu.com
14 Jul 23:32:45 ntpdate[27970]: ntpdate 4.2.4p8@1.1612-o Tue Apr 19 07:08:19 UTC 2011 (1)
Looking for host ntp.ubuntu.com and service ntp
host found : europium.canonical.com
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
transmit(91.189.94.4)
91.189.94.4: Server dropped: no data
server 91.189.94.4, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [91.189.94.4], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Wed, Feb  6 2036 22:28:16.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Wed, Feb  6 2036 22:28:16.000
transmit timestamp:  d3ace291.42321a2e  Sat, Jul 14 2012 23:32:49.258
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

14 Jul 23:32:50 ntpdate[27970]: no server suitable for synchronization found

real    0m4.755s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is relevant  but I guess may be due to this Change in [DNS from Ubuntu 12.04 Release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop)

> Network Manager now uses **dnsmasq** for improved DNS reliability and
>   support for split-DNS on VPN links. You can learn more [**here.**](http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/)